# Excluding events from Universal Analytics (opt_noninteraction)

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

Our website tracks clicks out to App Stores as custom events as a means of tracking conversions. However these external clicks are counted as bounces in GA, which we don't want as these are acceptable actions.

The old `ga.js` code would apparently allow something like:

`_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)`

with the final a boolean that, if `true` would exclude this event from bounce rate calculations. However `universal.js` doesn't appear to support this any more, the final parameter being the value:

`ga('send', 'event', 'Conversion', 'click', value, 1, true )`

So how can I achieve this in UA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no more a boolean value.

Here's an example

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Conversion', 'click', {'nonInteraction': 1});
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events